# Executing code before calling base class constructor

Tags: c++

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int a, int b);
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    static std::pair<int, int> determine_a_and_b_(int k);
public:
    explicit Derived(int k);
};

Derived::Derived(int k) :
    // a, b from determine_a_and_b_(k)...
    Base(a, b) { }
```

Is there any way to call `determine_a_and_b_` in the constructor of `Derived`, to get the values `a` and `b`, before calling `Base::Base`?

It seems that the only way would be to refactor `Base` so that it can first be default-constructed into a null object, and then be initialized with `a` and `b` later, like

```
Derived::Derived(int k) : Base() {
    Base::init_(a, b);
}
```

Is there any better way to do this, without needing to change `Base`?

**Edit** - made `determine_a_and_b_` static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do here is write a function that returns a `Base` and in the function create the base from the `std::pair` returned by `determine_a_and_b_`.  This allows you to conditionally initialize base in the member initialization list.  You would have something like

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int a, int b);
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    static std::pair<int, int> determine_a_and_b_(int k);
    static Base create_base(const std::pair<int, int>& params) { return Base(params.first, params.second); }
public:
    explicit Derived(int k);
};

Derived::Derived(int k) : Base(create_base(determine_a_and_b_(k)) {}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `determine_a_and_b_` and `create_base` have to be `static` to avoid depending on an uninitialized object?

Answer (score 3):

Calling member functions before your constructor even starts running is always shady. You end up running code on an object that is not yet constructed.

One alternative is to derive from a second base. That base class is inited first, picks a and b, and you then use those to init your second base class:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int a, int b){};
};

class Params
{
protected:
    Params()
    {
    // this replaces std::pair<int, int> determine_a_and_b_(int k);
    // put your logic here
        _values.first = 0;
        _values.second = 1;
    }
    std::pair<int, int> _values;
};

class Derived : public Params, public Base {
private:
public:
    explicit Derived(int k);
};

Derived::Derived(int k) :
    Base(_values.first, _values.second) 
{

}
```

Comment: Nice, but that permanently embiggens `Derived` by 2 `int`s. Each object stores `a` and `b` forever.